# Universal framework using Xcode 8.3?

Tags: xcode8, universal, swift-custom-framework

I'm trying to build universal swift framework. When I completed developing framework following several tutorials such as

https://medium.com/swiftindia/build-a-custom-universal-framework-on-ios-swift-549c084de7c8

[Creating a universal framework using Xcode 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890114/creating-a-universal-framework-using-xcode-8)

Also by using Aggregate target as well but fail to run in Simulator.

**Note:** I developed using Swift 3, Xcode Version 8.3

I tried with tutorials scripts too but fail.

Also my framework Xcode extension is **xcodeproj**.

My question is How to develop universal swift framework which will be release to client where he can test through Simulator as well as with real device?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26691080/614154) instruction and successfully build swift framework.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26691080/614154

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the following script. Supporting Swift and Simulator as well.

1. just add the content under Project Settings -> Build Phase as new Run Script Phase
2. Build Project
3. Folder will open, showing your zipped framework

https://gist.github.com/PaulEhrhardt/6d2be145c5d1b51c216914e7f032013e

```
#!/bin/sh

# iOS universal library build script supporting swift modules inclusive simulator slices

# prevention from running xcodebuild in a recusive way
if [ "true" == ${ALREADYINVOKED:-false} ]; then
    echo "RECURSION: Detected, stopping"
else
    export ALREADYINVOKED="true"

# output directory for universal framework
UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/iOS"

# build both device and simulator versions for iOS
xcodebuild -project "${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj" -scheme "${PROJECT_NAME}"  -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8' ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO clean build
xcodebuild -project "${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj" -scheme "${PROJECT_NAME}" -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO clean build

# copy the framework structure from iphoneos build to the universal folder
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/iOS"

# copy existing Swift modules from iphonesimulator build to the universal framework directory
SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/Modules/${PROJECT_NAME}.swiftmodule/"
if [ -d "${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR}" ]; then
    cp -R "${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR}" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/iOS/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/Modules/${PROJECT_NAME}.swiftmodule"
fi

# create universal binary file using lipo and place the combined executable in the universal framework directory
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/iOS/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}"

# intermediate step for copying the framework to the project's directory
mkdir -p "${TMPDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/Frameworks/iOS"
cp -R "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/iOS/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${TMPDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/Frameworks/iOS"

# create a zip file and move it to the project's directory
cd "${TMPDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/Frameworks/iOS"
zip -r "${PROJECT_NAME}.framework.zip" "${PROJECT_NAME}.framework"
mkdir -p "${PROJECT_DIR}/universal-framework"
mv "${PROJECT_NAME}.framework.zip" "${PROJECT_DIR}/universal-framework"

# optional: show the project's directory in Finder
open "${PROJECT_DIR}/universal-framework"
fi
```

Comment: Works! Thank you :)

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Xcode 11 with a framework project.