# Issues building react native project in xcode with m1 chip

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am trying to build a react native project in xcode to ipad simulator

but I get this error in xcode

```
remark: Incremental compilation has been disabled: it is not compatible with whole module optimization
Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I have seen this thread
[remark: Incremental compilation has been disabled: it is not compatible with whole module optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68801998/remark-incremental-compilation-has-been-disabled-it-is-not-compatible-with-who)

Have tried everything but nothing is making any difference

The build settings were already set to incremental

I dont see anything useful under `Compile swift source files` above the error...
It starts out as below, (there is more to it but nothing that is very human readable)

```
CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'ExpoModulesCore' from project 'Pods')
  cd /Users/alex/Documents/Projects/AtlasProject/src/frontend/packages/mobile/ios/Pods
  export DEVELOPER_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
  export SDKROOT\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc -incremental -module-name ExpoModulesCore -Onone -whole-module-optimization
```

If I run `yarn ios` which I believe runs `react-native run-ios` I get this error

```
We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 70
```

I am using:

```
macOs 12.4
Chip Apple M1 Pro
Xcode 13.4
react-native: 0.67.1
pod 1.11.3
node 15.6.0
ruby 2.6.8p205
```

I tried downgrading xcode previously which did not help,
And a co worker of mine is capable of creating ipad builds on his m1 mac with xcode 13.4,
unfortunately they do not know why it isnt working on my mac

I am also getting additional errors relating to react-native-webrtc, all of which are basically just `file not found`

Comment: Which React-Native version did you installed?

Comment: react-native: 0.67.1