# App crashed when launched in Xcode 13.2.1 in iOS 15.2 simulator in debug mode

Tags: ios, swift, crash, ios15, xcode13.2

I recently downloaded Xcode 13.2.1. When I run the application it is crashing in iOS 15.2 in simulator while debugging. Also when already installed app i am launching by tapping on app icon it is running fine.

Here are backtrace:

```
  thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)
  frame #0: 0x00007fff20198d24 libobjc.A.dylib`class_createInstance + 125
  frame #1: 0x00007fff20112f66
  frame #2: 0x00007fff20118c19
  frame #3: 0x00007fff265e625d
  frame #4: 0x00007fff2011383a
  frame #5: 0x00007fff20114a0d
  frame #6: 0x00007fff265ff8c6
  frame #7: 0x00007fff265ffc0b
  frame #8: 0x00007fff265ff214
  frame #9: 0x00007fff2011383a
  frame #10: 0x00007fff20114a0d
  frame #11: 0x00007fff265ff1ee
  frame #12: 0x00007fff35e0245b NetworkExtension`+[NEFilterSource filterRequired] + 35
  frame #13: 0x00007fff298dde70 WebKit`WebKit::WebPageProxy::createNetworkExtensionsSandboxExtensions(WebKit::WebProcessProxy&) + 52
  frame #14: 0x00007fff298ddc99 WebKit`WebKit::WebPageProxy::addPlatformLoadParameters(WebKit::WebProcessProxy&, WebKit::LoadParameters&) + 95
  frame #15: 0x00007fff29988216 WebKit`WebKit::WebPageProxy::loadRequestWithNavigationShared(WTF::Ref<WebKit::WebProcessProxy, WTF::RawPtrTraits<WebKit::WebProcessProxy> >&&, WTF::ObjectIdentifier<WebCore::PageIdentifierType>, API::Navigation&, WebCore::ResourceRequest&&, WebCore::ShouldOpenExternalURLsPolicy, API::Object*, WebCore::ShouldTreatAsContinuingLoad, std::__1::optional<WebKit::NavigatingToAppBoundDomain>, std::__1::optional<WebKit::WebsitePoliciesData>&&, std::__1::optional<WTF::ObjectIdentifier<WebKit::NetworkResourceLoadIdentifierType> >) + 1060
  frame #16: 0x00007fff29987d0d WebKit`WebKit::WebPageProxy::loadRequest(WebCore::ResourceRequest&&, WebCore::ShouldOpenExternalURLsPolicy, API::Object*) + 787
  frame #17: 0x00007fff2983ac3b WebKit`-[WKWebView loadRequest:] + 137
  frame #18: 0x000000010c7448fa SonyLIV`___lldb_unnamed_symbol7230$$SonyLIV + 73
  frame #19: 0x000000010c6fee83 SonyLIV`___lldb_unnamed_symbol5787$$SonyLIV + 88
  frame #20: 0x000000010c6ff502 SonyLIV`GADDispatchAsyncSafeMainQueue + 45
  frame #21: 0x000000010c6fec3d SonyLIV`___lldb_unnamed_symbol5780$$SonyLIV + 211
  frame #22: 0x000000010c72aa00 SonyLIV`___lldb_unnamed_symbol6756$$SonyLIV + 622
  frame #23: 0x000000010c73e9fe SonyLIV`___lldb_unnamed_symbol7124$$SonyLIV + 207
  frame #24: 0x0000000114e1e848 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
  frame #25: 0x0000000114e1fa2c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
  frame #26: 0x0000000114e2e1f1 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1197
  frame #27: 0x00007fff2036c84d CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
  frame #28: 0x00007fff203670aa CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2772
  frame #29: 0x00007fff203660f3 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
  frame #30: 0x00007fff2c995cd3 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 139
  frame #31: 0x00007fff25059f42 UIKitCore`-[UIApplication _run] + 928
  frame #32: 0x00007fff2505eb5e UIKitCore`UIApplicationMain + 101
  frame #33: 0x000000010ba20e9f SonyLIV`main at AppDelegate.swift:18:7
  frame #34: 0x000000011247dee9 dyld_sim`start_sim + 10
  frame #35: 0x000000011e4ea4fe dyld`start + 462
```

This crash I am getting in simulator only in device it is running fine.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

### Reason

---

The error here is `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, and it is occurring because of `___lldb_unnamed_symbol`.

### Fix

---

As there is no minimally reproducible code or the complete crash log.

- Assuming you are using the **Debug schema** check if a framework in your project had been compiled for **Release builds**, if that's the case change the schema to Debug for that framework.

Comment: From where we can check this? Also the app is running fine in iOS 14.X and running fine in real device having iOS 15.2.

Comment: [Refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34643933/8704774) to know how to change between Debug and Release. There isn't much info that you have given if all the frameworks are set to Debug; you will eventually get to know where exactly your app is crashing. The app works fine on a device is mostly because it doesn't need to build everything when running. Supposedly the issue could be as simple as a failed assertion. If you have a minimally reproducible code only then, I can help you. This is not a generic issue that could have a general fix. The fix could be simple or fairly complex.

Comment: If you can't share the code, I might say you start looking after where `WebKit-[WKWebView loadRequest:]` ([load:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414954-load)) has been called. [Refer to this](https://github.com/DerekSelander/LLDB) Set a breakpoint at that line and check using `lookup -X -l`. If it crashed earlier, use `sbt`.